# pointer array equivalence in C using arrays of different dimensions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've looked at other questions and they don't seem to answer this issue.

I have a routine that I'd like to process an integer array which may be one dimensional or two dimensional

so:

```
int myarray[10];
```

or

```
int myarray[10][10];
```

```
void myroutine(int *input_array, int num_dimens)
{
   int digits;
   int limbs;
   int i, j;

   digits = get_num_digits();
   if (num_dimens == 1)
   {
      for(i=0; i< digits; i++)
         myprocess(*(input_array+i));
   } else { /* 2 dimensions */
      limbs = get_num_limbs();
      for(j=0;j<limbs;j++)
         for(i=0; i< digits; i++)
           myprocess(*(input_array+j*digits+i));
   }
}
```

How do I call *myroutine*?

```
myroutine(myarray, 1);
myroutine(myarray2, 2);
```

This does not seem to work.
NEW EDIT:  Tried to flesh out the example further.

Comment: ...that would really depend on how `myroutine` actually works...

Comment: Any reason why you don't make 2 functions instead of 1?

Comment: You need one contiguous block, `int myarray[10 * 10]`, and do your own indexing arithmetic. And there's no "pointer array equivalence".

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't change the problem with compiling the code.

Comment: The array is generated elsewhere and is either 1 or 2 dimensional.

Comment: Pointers and arrays are not equivalent! And array **name** is sometimes implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: What is the problem with an outer dimension of `1`?

Comment: Do you mean having a 1 dimensional array represented as array[10][1]  or array[1][10]?  That's a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work because *myarray* decays into `int[10]`, however *myarray2* decays into `int(*)[10]`. If you really want to use one function, you should disable type checking by using a `void` pointer:

```
void myroutine(void *input_array, int num_dimens)
/*             ^^^^                             */
{
   /* stuff here */
}
```

Alternatively, you may "cheat" and keep your signature, but instead of calling `myroutine(myarray2, 2)` you should use:

```
myroutine(myarray2[0], 2)
```

Comment: The type of `myarray` is `int [10]`, not `int *` (the correct way to say it is that it *decays* into `int *` when passed to a function). Likewise, `myarray2` would *decay* into `int (*)[10]`, not `int **`. Also, pointer arithmetic is non-existent for `void` pointers, because there's no information about the size of the underlying type.

Comment: This is the only answer that makes the compiler happy.  The other answers are non-responsive to the question.

Comment: @Jiminion - But...   `myarray2[0]` doesn't have two dimensions, so how is it working?

Comment: @Jiminion but as soon as you start implementing, and calling, the function you'll find pacifying the compiler was the least of your problems. The compiler isn't trying to be annoying, its trying to help you avoid risky code. Lying to it doesn't fix the riskiness.

Comment: If the alternative is impossible, then what remains, however risky, is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you *really do* want to write a pseudo-polymorphic function that can handle different array types (meaning, different numbers of dimensions and lengths), you'll need to pass an explicit pointer to the first element:

```
myroutine( &myarray[0], 1 );
myroutine( &myarray2[0][0], 2 );
```

that way your first input is always an `int *`.

Within your routine, you'll have the treat the `input_array` object as a 1D array:

```
// input_array is a 1D array
input_array[i] = something;

// input_array is a 2D array
input_array[ i * d0 + j ] = something;

// input_array is a 3D array
input_array[i * d0 * d1 + j * d1 + k ] = something;
```

You'll want to pass the dimension lengths as additional arguments, something like:

```
myroutine( &myarray[0], 1, 10 );
myroutine( &myarray2[0][0], 2, 10, 10 );
myroutine( &myarray3[0][0][0], 3, 10, 10, 10 );
```

which you'd handle as follows:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
...
void myroutine( int *input_array, int num_dimens, ... ) // ... for additional arguments specifying dimension lengths
{
  va_alist ap;
  size_t *dims = malloc( num_dimens * sizeof *dims );

  va_start( ap, num_dimens );
  for ( int i = 0; i < num_dimens; i++ )
  {
    dims[i] = va_arg( ap, int ); 
  }
  va_end( ap );
  ...
```

And then, based on the number of dimensions, you can handle your input_array differently:

```
  switch( num_dimens )
  {
    case 1:
      input_array[i] = value;
      break;

    case 2:
      input_array[i * dims[0] + j] = value;
      break;

    case 3:
      input_array[i * dims[0] * dims[1] * j * dims[1] * k ] = value;
      break;
    ...
  }
  ...
  free( dims );
}
```

Of course, you'll have to figure out how you're looping through a 1D array vs. a 2D array vs. a 3D array, etc.  As the others have suggested, you're really better off creating separate functions for each number of dimensions.  You can use the pseudo-polymorphic function as a wrapper for them, but you'd lose the benefit of type safety.

**Edit**

Have the pointer to the first element generated along with the array itself:

```
int *ptr;

#if 1D
int myarray[10];
ptr = &myarray[0];
#else
int myarray[10][10];
ptr = &myarray[0][0];
#endif
```

then call as

```
myroutine( ptr, 1, 10 );
```

or

```
myroutine( ptr, 2, 10, 10 );
```

Comment: I think one needs to have a void pointer for input_array, otherwise the compiler barfs.  (NOTE:  Someone else is predefining input array to be either input[A][B] or input[A]. )

Comment: @Jiminion: `&myarray[0]` and `&myarray2[0][0]` are both going to have type `int *` (as long as both arrays are declared `int`).

Comment: The compiler will still barf at myarray[0][0] if it was pre-defined as myarray[x],  (and vice-versa).

Comment: @Jiminion: sorry, was using `myarray` as a general placeholder; obviously, you'd use different arrays with different dimensions - `myroutine( &myarray[0], 1, 10 );` vs. `myroutine(&myarray2[0][0], 2, 10, 10);`, etc.

Comment: @Jiminion: edited the answer to use different array names for arrays of different dimensions.

Comment: There is only 1 input array.  It either has one dimension or two.  So any call (even conditionally) which refers to a different dimensionality of the input array, will cause the compiler to reject it.

Comment: @Jiminion: then the call needs to be generated along with the array.  At least if you're going to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Write two separate functions, each handling one case. You want to keep the compiler type checking working in your favor. The cases are really different anyways. To index a 1D array, you need one int, for 2D array you need two ints and the information about the width of the table.

You can also extract the duplicated logic of both methods into a separate function, but do that after everything is working correctly.

Comment: The incoming array is either myarray[10] or myarray[10][10].  So two functions doesn't help, because both array variations need to be (conditionally) exposed, which causes the compiler to reject the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend making 2 functions, that in turn possibly call a common worker function. Proper program design is always better than using/abusing more or less obscure language mechanisms.

That being said, the code won't compile because in the 2D array case, you pass an array pointer to a function expecting a pointer to int. If you insist on doing this, either cast to `void*` or make the function take a `void*` parameter.

Comment: @Jiminion No, it's `int (*)[N]` (pointer to array of `N` elements), where `N` is the size of the second dimension.

Comment: Other than the indexing issues, how is int ** not the same as int (*) [N]?

Comment: The first is a pointer to a pointer to int, the second is a pointer to a table of `N` elements of type `int`.

Comment: @Jiminion There is no "equivalence". There are pointers, there are arrays, there are pointers to pointers, there are pointers to arrays, all of these are different things. An array is not "equivalent" to a pointer. But when an array name is used as part of an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to the first element. The first element of a 2D array is an array, so when a 2D array decays as you pass it as parameter to the function, you get a pointer to an array. These things are somewhat complex but you don't even need to bother about them if you keep your code sound and simple, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach for handling a 2D array of unknown dimensions. It uses variable length array (VLA)<sup>1</sup> syntax to properly declare a pointer to the array.

```
void foo( int rows, int cols, int (*array2d)[cols] )
{
    int value = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
        for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
            array2d[i][j] = value++;
}

int main( void )
{
    // declare an array
    int myarray[5][10];

    // initialize the array
    foo( 5, 10, myarray );

    // show the array
    for ( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
    {
        for ( int col = 0; col < 10; col++ )
            printf( "%2d ", myarray[row][col] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>VLAs were introduced in C99, but compiler support for VLAs is optional as of C11.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[For the sake of readability I changed 10 to 4 and made the 2D array asymmetric]

```
int a[4];
```

is an element of

```
int b[3][4];
```

So make your function aware of the 2D-array and pass a pointer to its element, along with the number of elements.

```
void f(int (*)[4], size_t);
```

and call it like this

```
f(&a, 1);
```

or

```
f(b, 3);
```

Inside the function access the element(s) like this:

```
void f(int (*c)[4], size_t s)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
      printf ("c[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, c[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int (*)[4], size_t);

int main (void)
{
  int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  int b[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};

  printf("a:\n");
  f(&a, 1);
  printf("b:\n");
  f(b, 3); /* b decays to a pointer to its 1st element. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a structure like

```
struct Array1or2 {
  int *data;
  unsigned DimCount;
  // If not always width 10, add unsigned Width;
};
```

Create functions like

```
void Array1or2_Create(struct Array1or2 *A, unsigned Dims);
void Array1or2_Destroy(struct Array1or2 *A);

// Get value with only X
int Array1or2_X(const struct Array1or2 *A, unsigned x);
// Get value with X & Y
int Array1or2_XY(const struct Array1or2 *A, unsigned x, unsigned x);
```

---

Sample implementations

```
void Array1or2_Create(struct Array1or2 *A, unsigned Dims) {
  assert(Dims >= 1 && Dims <= 2); 
  A->DimCount = Dims;
  size_t size = sizeof *(A->data);
  while (Dims > 0) size *= 10;
  A->data = malloc(size);
  assert(A->data); 
}

int Array1or2_X(const struct Array1or2 *A, unsigned x) {
  assert(x < 10); 
  return A->data[x];
}

int Array1or2_XY(const struct Array1or2 *A, unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  assert(x < 10 && y < 10); 
  if (A->DimCount < 2) return 0;
  return A->data[x + 10*y];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't change the organization of the incoming array, which is either a 1-D or 2-D integer array.